# Connecting to my Mac from my PC

Tags: windows-7, mac

I've been trying to figure out how to connect to my Mac from my PC (when on the same network).

I ended up figuring out the address to use, and this worked:

1. On my PC, I press Start, type "run" and hit enter. (opens up the run dialog)
2. I enter an address (e.g. `\\192.177.1.2\`)
3. It opens up with the folders on my Mac.

However, can't I just store this address location in My Computer in the Network section so that I don't have to type it each time and use the run dialog? Any ideas of how I can get it to stay up?

Comment: Map a drive to one of the folders that open up?

Comment: how do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

On your windows pc

1. Go to my computer
2. There should be a map network drive (win 7/vista) or click tools and then map network drive (win xp)
3. there should be a button or text link that says "connect to a network server" click that
4. When you get a list of options choose "specify another network location"
5. enter the address of yor mac. its probably best to use the name of the computer rather than the ip
6. there will be a dialogue that says if you want to login anonymously or with a username/pass (use anonymous)
7. finish the rest of the wizard
8. there should be a shortcut to it in my computer.

Comment: BTW, you can drag the icon in the address bar of any explorer window to any folder and it will create a shortcut for you. In Windows Vista / 7, you can easily drag it to the Favorites section on the left panel. It's generally easier if mapping network drives don't work very well.

Comment: hm. thanks for your response. when I followed steps 1-4, it is asking me now for a username and password. before, when I used the run dialog, I didn't have to enter a username and password. and I'm not sure what username and password to use and I can't figure out one that works.

Comment: Weird. You could make a shortcut to it. But im assuming that your router uses dhcp so the mac could have a different ip every time its turned on.

Comment: @CodeGuy try doing it the new way, as it adds a shortcut not mapping it as a network drive.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to control your Mac from your PC's keyboard, monitor, and mouse then use VNC.  Download one of the many free VNC viewers and install it on your PC then on the Mac enable remote viewing.  See [this site](http://www.wikihow.com/Setup-VNC-on-Mac-OS-X) for how to setup the remote viewing/desktop.  I use a VNC viewer/server on my PC so I can control the PC from the Mac as well.

Comment: Somehow I don't think this is what the OP meant.